# Will creating functions starting with plus or minus (like `+project(){}`) cause unintended side effects?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

This works but I don't know what the side effects are.

Example creating & removing python virtualenv using virtualenvwrapper:

```
+v() {
  mkvirtualenv --python=$(which python3) ${1:-${PWD##*/}}
}

-v() {
  deactivate
  rmvirtualenv ${1:-${PWD##*/}}
}
```

*(`${1:-${PWD##*/}}` defaults to working directory name if there's no $1)*

`+` and `-` are my primary concern but I'm also curious about characters like `»`

```
»deploy(){
  # ...
}
```

(`»` can be typed with <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+`\` on a Mac, if you're wondering why I'd bother to use a special character.)

Comment: "»" is Unicode U+00bb, regardless of how you might enter it with your keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, the zsh man page doesn't seem to define, what legally can go into a function name. On my zsh, all three of your examples work, thought for reason of portability, I would stay away from any name which can not be represented in the 7-Bit ASCII world - at least in productive code. It's just begging for trouble.

If you use these functions only in your working environment (for instance defined in your .zshrc) and are happy with such funny names, feel free to use them. At least the likelihood to have a name clash with a function coming from some other project, is low.